# I have a question about how to use css::before

Tags: html, css

```css
footer .menu li::before {
  content: "";
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #555;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: -1px;
}

footer .menu li:last-child::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="inner">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="green">개인정보처리방침</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">영상정보처리기기 운영관리 방침</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">홈페이지 이용약관</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">위치정보 이용약관</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">스타벅스 카드 이용약관</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">윤리경영 핫라인</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

The result came out like this. However, I used `::before`, so I think there must be a point before. Why is the result coming out like this?

[image]

I think

[image]

Comment: It's using `position: absolute` and shoving the `::before` element to the right using `right: -1px;`. So it doesn't matter whether it's using `::before` or `::after`. Also there's a `display: none` on the `::before` of the last element. So the right-most one is missing the `::before` element on the right side

Comment: please insert the whole css of footer from `footer` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using with `position: absolute;`. You should write `left: -1px;` because if you write `right: -1px;` then your this absolute block starts on the right side and do not forget that you should also use `position: relative;` for `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

:before is an element that will be added before the target in html. But in your style, you set the position of it in **absolute** and you set the **right to -1px**

You just need to position it before the element with a `left` tag.

You could use a `:not(:first-child)` selector to prevent the :before to be generated for the first child of your list.

I've done an example :

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.foo {
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.foo:not(:first-child):before {
    font-size: 30px;
    top: -5px;
    content: "·";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left:-15px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
</div>
```